# returning outer function from inner function

Tags: javascript

```
function MyFunction () {

   if (SomeCondition) {

      MyInnerFunction(SomeParam);
      return;
   }   

   if (SomeOtherCondition) {

      MyInnerFunction(SomeOtherParam);
      return;
   } 

   if (SomeThirdCondition) {

      MyInnerFunction(AnotherParam);
      return;
   } 

   function MyInnerFunction(Param) {

      // Do some work here
      // HERE: I want return from MyFunction
   }
}
```

As you can see, when `MyInnerFunction` returns, the next statement to execute is the `return` statement of `MyFunction`. Is there a way to eliminate all these return statements so that the return from `MyFunction` executes inside `MyInnerFunction`?

Thanks.

Comment: No, there is not.  What you want is impossible.  The inner function has no control on the outer.  You could use `return MyInnerFunction(AnotherParam);` instead.

Comment: How about `else if` ?

Comment: Do you have any other code in `MyFunction`?  Why not just remove all the `return;` lines?

Comment: why not just add the return to the same line that you're calling the function (and ensure the inner function doesn't return anything)?  If you want to really write some obtuse code to get where you want without following a logical stack progression you could also abuse try/catch (obviously not recommended...unless it actually makes sense).

Comment: I concur with @Prinzhorn, an `else if` or a `switch` should do the trick.

Comment: @RocketHazmat: if I remove the multiple returns then all the conditions will be evaluated before returning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you could reformat the code so that your if conditions are only modifying the parameters.
Then you just call your method with the correct parameters at the end

```
function MyFunction () {
   var params; 

   if (SomeCondition)
      params = SomeParam;
   else if (SomeOtherCondition)
      params = SomeOtherParam;
   else if (SomeThirdCondition)
      params = AnotherParam;

   MyInnerFunction(params);
}
```

Comment: No, each "if(Condition)" statement still gets executed even after MyInnerFunction executes. The reason I have all these return statements is that once MyInnerFunction executes, MyFunction returns immediately and none of the other if statements are evaluated.

Comment: why do you not want the conditionals executed?

Comment: Because there's no need to, only one condition will ever run.

Comment: you could change it to else if, then only one should be executed and the others skipped over.